# Switch inductive load: relay instead of switch

Tags: inductive

I have a transformer based AC fan regulator with five output steps. The regulator has a manual rotary switch (5 steps) which selects different windings on the secondary coil to give different output voltage (240-120V). I would like to replace the switch with something I can interface from a microcontroller.

Can I assume the regulator already contains circuitry to handle the inductive load discharges while breaking current, so it should be safe to simply put in a relay (one relay for each output step) instead of a switch? Or is a relay more sensitive to voltage spikes than a manual switch, so I would need some extra protection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the relay contacts in parallel with the switch contacts, they will have whatever protection the existing circuit provides. But you should inspect the existing circuit to ensure for yourself that it really does have protection.

That said, putting five relays on those taps is almost certainly a REALLY BAD IDEA. A rotary switch is guaranteed to select only one transformer tap at a time. You have no such guarantee with five separate relays controlled by microcontroller... it is highly likely you'll end up turning two relays on at once, which will present a short circuit between two taps of the transformer, and result in a fiery demise.

So... don't do that please!

Comment: Two active relays at a time must be prevented of course. I was thinking to use an address decoder such as 74HC137 to activate the relays. The microcontroller would just send an address to the address decoder, and the mutually exclusive outputs of the decoder make sure the relays activated only one at a time. Is this sane?

Comment: Relay contacts can get stuck.

Comment: I would say it's still pretty insane to have any way for a controller to even by accident create a short across a portion of a mains transformer. There are multiple ways this could fail and in the process turn on multi relays. Of course, you will have a fuse upstream from the transformer, right?

Comment: Ah, good point @freyyr. Is there a similar risk with SSRs? Is there really no standard component available as the electronic alternative to a manual rotary switch?

Comment: Well there are motorized rotary switches, which are basically multi-position relays.

Comment: Example: Old-school traffic-light controllers: http://www.kbrhorse.net/signals/controllers01.html

Comment: The "motorized rotary switch" clue led me to a patent from 1960, pictures from analog telephone switch boards, and other antiques. I take it as a (yet another) hint that I am probably not on the right track :) I will get an electronically interfaceable AC fan controller instead. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Good call. Engineering break before make can get weird. Just wanted to point out that the address decoder would have made that even harder, given nanosecond response times. A microcontroller could intentionally insert proper delays, and check for stuck relays.

Answer (score 1):

Second gwideman's opinion of things.

If you really wanted to, you might be able to play with the rotary switch to attach some sort of actuator to it, like a servo or some such. But that sounds kind of Frankenstein to me.

The relay system becomes quite workable, though, as long as you install interlocks. It would be a small investment to route B-contacts on relays to electrically prevent accidentally (through code or operator error) switching any two relays at a time. That and little bit of switch debouncing could work beautifully, if you are exceedingly careful.

Comment: Interesting point. I don't dispute that an interlock using additional relay contacts would be possible... how do you see it working on 5 relays like this? Just curious, I haven't had to think very deeply in "relay logic" :-).

Comment: It takes a lot more wire, that's for sure. The better answer is to use a PLC, really. But if you're hacking hardware, the B-contact on the relay just has to break one side of the coil path for the other four relays, while ensuring that its own coil path remains intact. This would get complicated unless the chosen relay actually had four available B-contacts - thats not exactly a common case, but neither is it incredibly rare. Relay closes, b-contacts open, voila! I suppose if you really had to you could route the common returns through a single contact, but that gets hideous.

Comment: Darn I was hoping you had some clever trick up your sleeve to avoid needing so many B contacts!

Comment: I am a bit surprised there is no standard component available as the electronic alternative to a manual rotary switch. The complex wiring to get mutual exclusiveness are already in an address decoder such as 74HC137, so what is left is just adding a relay on each output line.

Comment: @Eivind, hadn't thought of that. Of course digital logic would handle that smashingly. It is worth pointing out though that some relays need more current than a typical CMOS encoder will push, and may require a current follower. But brilliantly thought.

Comment: Thanks, but I would be in trouble if a relay contact gets stuck as @freyyr points out. Your B-contact network would safeguard against this as well. Not sure how to judge whether my design is "safe enough" or not. Using SSRs instead of relays may reduce the risk of stuck contacts? Can I add fuses in the circuit and rely upon them to prevent a "fiery demise" (quoting @gwideman)?

Comment: Well, any transformer based design needs fuse protection on the primary side, to prevent just such an event. Ever seen a transformer eat itself? Pretty wild stuff. No need really to scatter fuses through the whole circuit, just estimate worst case full load for normal conditions, add maybe 10 to 20 percent and then pick the lowest fuse rating above that. The existing transformer your using stands a good chance of already having one, or an equivalent circuit breaker.